# How to design a complicated form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I need to create a form in React made of multiple components, such as `<TextField>, <DropDown>, <DatePicker>` where each one has a different props, some of them are common such as `Id, Label`

Question is how should I program this, I have come with a few ideas ->

1. It would be easier to split it into separate arrays: `dropdowns, textFields, datePickers` and then render them via `.map()`, but it wouldn't work as they are not in order in the form
2. Put all of components into array and render them via `.map()` with if/switch/function where I would decide which component is which

```
 const App = (props) => {
  const forms = props.forms
  const getItem(type) {
    if (type === Type.DropDown) {
      return <Dropdown dropDownProps>
    }
    ....
  }
  return (
    forms.map(item => {
      return getItem(item.type)
    })
  )
}
```

- Next question is how/where to store all props - there is about 10 of these fields in the form, so should I do some file like InitData.ts with

```
const FirstField = {id: 0, label: "FirstField"}
...
```

but then how would I pass props such as `onChange` etc?

- Also how should I store all those inputs using hooks? Array of strings, or some object?

Comment: why dont you use soething like Formik or react final-form.

Comment: Well I already have those components TextField etc.. available. I dont need library for it, I just need an advice how to program it in a "nice" way :)

Comment: this is the advice. all of the above packages need you to use your own components, they just help with easy state management as well as validation etc. you will still use your textfiled etc just the state management you let the package handle

Comment: Okay, gonna take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always base your components on abstraction and try to make them reusable, so assume I want to create a login form.

I would create a folder called **common** having common components, like text field and dropdowns as a way of reusing them.

and then another component for wrapping up most of the functionalities: handling submit events, handling form validation, render input, render dropdown. Most of these functionalities are core in my form, so abstract them away into a separate component called **form** component.

finally, I create another component called **loginForm**, in which I call these functionalities to render them.

I store the initial field values of type empty strings in a state hook inside **loginform** and pass it as an argument to the props of the **form** component.